# What storage engines work with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, storage-engine

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine

mentions about database engines aka storage engines. What all storage engines can be used with the Oracle database?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oracle is not like MySQL in this. Like most other RDBMSs it comes with it's own built-in storage engine that cannot be exchanged for another.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, whilst Jack's answer is technically true, it is possible to use [Data Cartridges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dciwhatis.htm) to expand on vanilla Oracle offerings.

In fact, a company called CopperEye released a new indexing method ([patented](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/09006361800749b3.pdf), now not available) utilizing this functionality. See [this old press release](http://www.sourcewire.com/news/15594/coppereye-announces-a-key-innovative-step-in-data-indexing-technology). The patent makes for fascinating reading.

Comment: learn something new every day with Oracle..

Comment: Interesting. @Phil, do you have a link to that (fascinating) patent?

Comment: Indeedy. http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/09006361800749b3.pdf